# After M1 to M2 migration, Checkout page blank (only logo is showing)

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, checkout-page, data-migration

I've migrated from Magento 1.9.3.4 to Magento 2.1.8 but when I goto checkout page (after adding a product to cart) it shows empty page, the only logo is showing, while other pages are fine.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: can you check var/log/system.log file any error show ?

Comment: check log messages

Comment: I got the issue in system.log,  please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I checked system.log found following error:-

**CRITICAL: Class celigoconnectorplus/carrier_shippingmethod does not exist.**

& when I checked core_config_data then I found 3 entries of celigoconnectorplus after deleting this entries issue has been resolved.